# How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R.  I want to try two different conditions on two different columns, but I want these conditions to be inclusive. Therefore, I would like to use "OR" to combine the conditions.  I have used the following syntax before with lot of success when I wanted to use the "AND" condition.

```
my.data.frame <- data[(data$V1 > 2) & (data$V2 < 4), ]
```

But I don't know how to use an 'OR' in the above.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
my.data.frame <- subset(data , V1 > 2 | V2 < 4)
```

An alternative solution that mimics the behavior of this function and would be more appropriate for inclusion within a function body:

```
new.data <- data[ which( data$V1 > 2 | data$V2 < 4) , ]
```

Some people criticize the use of `which` as not needed, but it does prevent the `NA` values from throwing back unwanted results. The equivalent (.i.e not returning NA-rows for any NA's in V1 or V2) to the two options demonstrated above without the `which` would be:

```
 new.data <- data[ !is.na(data$V1 | data$V2) & ( data$V1 > 2 | data$V2 < 4)  , ]
```

Note: I want to thank the anonymous contributor that attempted to fix the error in the code immediately above, a fix that got rejected by the moderators. There was actually an additional error that I noticed when I was correcting the first one. The conditional clause that checks for NA values needs to be first if it is to be handled as I intended, since ...

```
> NA & 1
[1] NA
> 0 & NA
[1] FALSE
```

Order of arguments may matter when using '&".

Comment: This is the highest voted question and then one finds:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: The advantage  is compactness and easy of comprehension. The disadvantage is lack of utility in function building tasks. If one wants to replicate this with `[` one needs to wrap in `which` or use additional `!is.na` constraints.

Comment: Is the 'which' required and if not why do you use it?

Comment: It's not "required", but you may get a different result if you leave out the `which`. If both V1 and V2 are NA you would get a row of NA's at that position if you left out the `which`. I work with large datasets and even a relatively small percentage of NA's will really fill up my screen with junk output. Some people think this is a feature. I don't.

Comment: how do you include a call to `grepl` or `grep` with this to also do pattern matching for desired rows, in addition to these conditionals?

Comment: `grepl` should work. If you have a counter-example, it would make a good new question.

Comment: `subset` IS robust to the existence of `NA`s in a dataframe: `vc <- data.frame(duzey=factor(c("Y","O","Y","D","Y","Y","O"), levels=c("D","O","Y"), ordered=TRUE),
cinsiyet=c("E","E","K",NA,"K","E","K"), yas=c(8,3,9,NA,7,NA,6), Not=c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,2,1)); vc; subset(vc, cinsiyet=="E" | Not<4); subset(vc, cinsiyet=="E" & Not<2)`. In some sources, `subset` is mentioned to be "interactive use only".

Comment: @42-, Many thanks for `NA & 1; 0 & NA # NA; FALSE`. I did not notice this nuance ever before. In the latter (`0 & NA`), why we get `FALSE` instead of `NA` as in `NA & 1 # NA`?

Comment: Subtle coercing: `class(0); class(1) # numeric; numeric`. However, different coercing works for `1& NA; 0 & NA # NA; FALSE`. Interesting !

Comment: `!is.na` solution seems to be more prone to warnings in factors upon comparison: `df <- data.frame(V1=factor(1:10), V2=factor(c(rep("L",2), rep("M",3), rep("H",5)))); df; df[which(df$V1 > 4 | df$V2 == "H"), ]; df[!is.na(df$V1 | df$V2) & (df$V1 > 4 | df$V2 == "H"), ]`

Comment: @42-, Thank you for the WHICH clarification. I was getting undesired results when using the "OR" or even the "AND" operator. Using "ifelse" for example, I think just one NA on one of the conditioning variables would yield NA result and not apply the "ELSE" condition...

Answer (score 34):

You are looking for "|."  See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Logical-vectors

```
my.data.frame <- data[(data$V1 > 2) | (data$V2 < 4), ]
```

Comment: This is NOT robust to the existence of `NA`s in a dataframe: `vc <- data.frame(duzey=factor(c("Y","O","Y","D","Y","Y","O"), levels=c("D","O","Y"), ordered=TRUE),
cinsiyet=c("E","E","K",NA,"K","E","K"), 
yas=c(8,3,9,NA,7,NA,6), Not=c(NA,1,1,NA,NA,2,1)); vc; vc[vc$cinsiyet == "E" | vc$Not < 4,]; vc[vc$cinsiyet == "E" & vc$Not < 2,]`

Answer (score 19):

Just for the sake of completeness, we can use the operators `[` and `[[`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(v1 = runif(10), v2 = letters[1:10])
```

Several options

```
df[df[1] < 0.5 | df[2] == "g", ] 
df[df[[1]] < 0.5 | df[[2]] == "g", ] 
df[df["v1"] < 0.5 | df["v2"] == "g", ]
```

df$name is [equivalent to](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) df[["name", exact = FALSE]]

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, v1 < 0.5 | v2 == "g")
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT *
      FROM df 
      WHERE v1 < 0.5 OR v2 = "g"')
```

Output for the above options:

```
          v1 v2
1 0.26550866  a
2 0.37212390  b
3 0.20168193  e
4 0.94467527  g
5 0.06178627  j
```

Comment: how would you do this for 1 AND condition and 3 OR conditions contingent so for example:  my.data.frame <- data[data$V3>10 & ((data$V1 > 2) | (data$V2 < 4) | (data$V4 <5), ]. When I do this it doesn't work

Comment: Wow! The `sqldf` package is too good. Very handy especially when `subset()` gets a bit painful :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for a very scalable solution that is applicable if you want to test multiple columns for the same condition, you can use `Reduce` or `rowSums`.

#### Sample Data

```
df <- base::expand.grid(x = c(0, 1),
                        y = c(0, 1),
                        z = c(0, 1))
df
#>   x y z
#> 1 0 0 0
#> 2 1 0 0
#> 3 0 1 0
#> 4 1 1 0
#> 5 0 0 1
#> 6 1 0 1
#> 7 0 1 1
#> 8 1 1 1
```

#### Solution

Does it contain any 0? Keeps every row except for row 8 that is filled with 1 only.

The function + in `Reduce()` basically works as an OR operator since its result is >0 if it contains any TRUE value.

```
## Reduce ---------------------------------------------------
df[Reduce(f = `+`, x = lapply(df, `==`, 0)) > 0, ]
#>   x y z
#> 1 0 0 0
#> 2 1 0 0
#> 3 0 1 0
#> 4 1 1 0
#> 5 0 0 1
#> 6 1 0 1
#> 7 0 1 1

## rowSums --------------------------------------------------
df[rowSums(df == 0) > 0, ]
#>   x y z
#> 1 0 0 0
#> 2 1 0 0
#> 3 0 1 0
#> 4 1 1 0
#> 5 0 0 1
#> 6 1 0 1
#> 7 0 1 1
```

#### Multiple AND-Conditions

Note that you can use `Reduce` also easily to apply multiple `AND` conditions by using `*` instead of `+`. Multiplying all logicals only returns a value `>0` if all cases are `TRUE`.

```
df[Reduce(`*`, lapply(df, `==`, 0)) > 0, ]
#>   x y z
#> 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option for completeness:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1 = runif(10, 0, 1),
                 V2 = letters[1:10])

dt[V1 > 0.5 | V2 == "b",]
#>           V1 V2
#> 1: 0.7294220  a
#> 2: 0.9717687  b
#> 3: 0.7177076  c
#> 4: 0.5963838  e
#> 5: 0.5456320  i
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

For more info about this useful package check this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).