# How do make a subset based on 2 criteria in R?

Tags: r, subset

I am working with the global terrorism database in R

I am trying to make a subset from the gtd called United Kingdom to include Great Britian and Northern Ireland.

I can do it for them individually with the code

```
 uk <- subset(x=gtd, country_txt=="Northern Ireland")
```

How can I also make this subset include data for Great Britian? I understand why using "&" doesn't work, but I don't know the right command to form the correct subset.

Comment: Can you use the OR operator rather than AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%in%` for inclusion or negation of a logical vector formed with it to do exclusion:

```
uk <- subset(x=gtd, country_txt %in% c("Great Britain", "Northern Ireland") )
```

To exclude members of that set:

```
not_uk <- subset(x=gtd, !country_txt %in% c("Great Britain", "Northern Ireland") )
```

Can also do that with `[`

```
uk <- gtk[ gtd$country_txt %in% c("Great Britain", "Northern Ireland") , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `&`  (not `&&`) or `%in%`

```
 country_txt=="Northern Ireland" | country_txt == "GB"
```

OR

```
 country_txt %in%  c("GB", "Northern Ireland")
```

if using `%in%`, make sure that the right-hand value is a vector (ie, use `c()`)

Comment: First one would have to be `|` not `&`

Comment: Thanks! what about if I want to exclude something? I am trying to perform similar to above, but I want to make a subset that excludes gname=="Irish Republican Army (IRA)"

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail.   BTW, feel free to edit my answers if/when I have a sloppy mistake like that

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to include both countries, you need to use a condition that is valid when the country text is *either* of the two - this implies an OR syntax. You could try

```
uk<- subset(x=gtd, (country_txt=="Northern Ireland") | (country_txt=="Great Britain") )
```

See [How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or) for more discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks! what about if I want to exclude something? I am trying to perform similar to above, but I want to make a subset that excludes gname=="Irish Republican Army (IRA)"