# OR operator in filter()?

Tags: r, filter, operators, dplyr

I want to use the `filter()` function to find the types that have an x value less than or equal to 4, OR a y value greater than 5. I think this might be a simple fix I just can't find much info on `?filter()`. I almost have it I think:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y = c(3, 6, 1, 9, 1, 1)
type = c("cars", "bikes", "trains")

df = data.frame(x, y, type)

df2 = df %>% 
      filter(x<=4)
```

Comment: `filter(x <=4 | y > 5)` doesn't work?

Comment: also, your example data is pretty crappy, since `y > 5` is a subset of `x <= 4`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Not sure what you mean because I just started programming. I just realized I screwed up the "type" part. I didn't know what `| ` did so thank you for that insight.

Comment: I mean, for your data, `filter(x<=4 | y > 5)` produces the same result as `filter(x<=4)`. For an instructive working example, there should be a difference

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935479/1191259 and type `?Syntax` in the R console for a full list of basic operators.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Oh, I see what you mean now. Yeah I should've looked out for that. I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
df %>%
    filter(x <=4| y>=5)
```