# select observations based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

For each subject, one observation (or row) is kept  based on the following:

if `var2=c and var3=B` then keep that observation.
if not, check `if var2=c and var3=S` and keep that observation.
if not, then then check  if `var2=L and var3=B`,
finally, check  if `var2=L and var3=S` , if not put 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

My data looks like this:

```
id   var1   var2    var3
1   100 L   S
1   100 L   B
1   2   C   B
1   2   C   S
2   5   C   S
2   10  L   S
2   NA  L   B
2   NA  C   B
```

My desired result is:

```
id   var1   var2    var3
1   2   C   B
2   5   C   S
```

Comment: I don't get it...Can you explain the conditions better please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The first code block -- where you show the assignment of values -- doesn't make sense. For instance "var2=c and var3=B if not then ". What do you mean "if not then"? What is being tested here? Do you mean "`if(var3=="B") {var2 <- "c"}`" and if that's not true then your next statement, etc?

Comment: Try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or

Comment: but for `id =2` you also have `C` and `B`. Why do you take `C` and `S`

Comment: but the var1 is missing in those cases.

Comment: by missing you mean it is `NA` or `''`?

Comment: yes its not measured. So, NA in those cases

Comment: I fixed incorrect spelling and capitalization but someone keeps changing it back to the wrong way...

Comment: @Hack-R That was probably me (the last time at least), I changed some `.` values to `NA` and I might missed something :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c('CB', 'CS', 'LB', 'LS') #vector with conditions
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  slice(order(match(paste0(var2, var3), x))[1])

#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id  var1   var2   var3
#  <int> <int> <fctr> <fctr>
#1     1     2      C      B
#2     2     5      C      S
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), var1 = c(100L, 
100L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 10L, NA, NA), var2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("C", "L"), class = "factor"), 
    var3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("B", 
    "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "var1", "var2", 
"var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks. you mean the condition CB has to be combined??

Comment: @sri It doesn't have to be combined but It is easier to compare and `match` based on 'importance'