# Multiple conditions in R using a specific variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements

i have a simple question. I have a big df like :

```
     Name  AGE  Order
       Anna  25    1
       Anna   28   2
       Peter 10    1
       Paul  15    1
       Mary  14    1
       John  8     1
       Charlie 24  2
       Robert  20  2
```

For just Order= 1 , I need filter AGE>=10 & AGE<=15. So output file must be:

```
       Name  AGE  Order
        Anna   28   2
        Peter 10    1
        Paul  15    1
        Mary  14    1
        Charlie 24  2
        Robert  20  2
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: Sorry. I need filter AGE>=10 & AGE<=15 just for Order =1.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or)

Answer (score 1):

We can use vectorized `ifelse`

For `Order = 1` check if `AGE` lies in the range of 10-15, select rest rows as it is.

```
df[ifelse(df$Order==1, df$AGE >= 10 & df$AGE <= 15, TRUE), ]

#    Name AGE Order
#2    Anna  28     2
#3   Peter  10     1
#4    Paul  15     1
#5    Mary  14     1
#7 Charlie  24     2
#8  Robert  20     2
```

We can also consolidate to:

```
subset(df, AGE >= 10 & AGE <= 15 | Order != 1)
```