# Efficiently combining multiple conditions on R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, conditional-statements

I'm working with data frames in R and often use a lot of conditions on my dataframes, mainly `&` and `|` operators. I'm doing that like so:

```
df = data.frame("col1"=c("success", "failure", "success"), "col2"=c("success", "success", "failure"), "col3"=c(1,1,100))
#multiple conditions, option 1
df[(df[["col1"]]=="success") & (df[["col2"]]=="success") & (df[["col3"]] == 1), ]
#multiple conditions, option 2
df[which((df[["col1"]]=="success") & (df[["col2"]]=="success") & (df[["col3"]] == 1)),]
```

However, my expressions tend to get really long and hard to read that way.

- Is there a better, more readable way of doing it?
- EDIT: Preferably, I'd like to work within the base R environment w/out external libraries.

I put this together based on other posts here on SO about [not using subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset), [using | correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or), but didnt' find anything addressing this specific issue.

I hope this is not too opinion-based, otherwise I'll retract my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `filter()` function in the [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) package:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, col1=="success" & col2=="success" & col3==1)
```

You can also use commas (equivalent to &) to separate multiple arguments:

```
filter(df, col1=="success", col2=="success", col3==1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't specify this in my question (my bad) but I was thinking standard package to make this more easily transferable. It's good to know about it though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (may be not clumsy but with same '&')

```
> df[df$col1=="success" & df$col2=="success" & df$col3==1,]
     col1    col2 col3
1 success success    1
```

Comment: cool, I just figured that might get me in trouble once I use it in a script or with variables, cause of the `$`.