# R subset of data frame for cohort analysis

Tags: r

I have following data in the data frame df

```
persons  year
personA  2015
personB  2016
personC  2015
personB  2015
```

how do I use subset function in R to filter personB who is in 2015 and 2016
I am using following Code, but does not work

```
df1 <- subset(df, (year==2015 & year ==2016))
```

Comment: The expected output is not clear.

Comment: i just corrected the dataframe. i want to get persons who are in both 2015 and 2016. personB is in both data frame.

Comment: You're close. This topic is covered extensively on SO and you may find a relevant example (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `dplyr` for this as it's much easier than in base R.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(persons) %>% filter(n() == 2)
```

This groups the rows by person and then retains only groups with two members (both years).

Comment: Just because `n()==2` doesn't mean they are both in 2015 and 2016. There could be two records for one year or records for two different years or they might be in 2015, 2106, and 2014 and would be missed.

Comment: Absolutely agree. I will think of editing to cover these cases.

Comment: I think `df %>% group_by(persons) %>% filter(all(2015:2016 %in% year))` should do the trick to require a value for those specific years (but still allow possible duplicates).

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- df[(df$year== 2015 | df$year== 2016),][1]

## get each person and the number of his appearence in the dataframe
t <- table(df2)
# 
# personA personB personC 
# 1       2       1 

t[t>1]
# personB 
# 2
```

The dataframe

```
df <- data.frame("persons" = c("personA","personB","personC","personB"),
 "year" = c(2015,2016,2015,2015))
```

**EDIT**

Another solution using `duplicated`

```
 duplicated(df$persons)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 df[duplicated(df$persons),1]
# personB
```

Comment: i want persons who are in both 2015 and 2016. i dont want to filter based on persons

Answer (score 0):

An example using `data.table` (and `unique` to handle multiple rows of same person in same year):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(persons = c("personA", "personB", "personC", "personB"
), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L)), .Names = c("persons", 
"year"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(dt)
years <- c("2015", "2016")
# Filter by years and make sure all rows are unique combinations of persons and
# thoese years. Then set in_all_years to TRUE of number of rows is equal to
# number of years
out <- unique(dt[year %in% years])[, in_all_years := .N == length(years),
  by = persons]

> out
   persons year in_all_years
1: personA 2015        FALSE
2: personB 2016         TRUE
3: personC 2015        FALSE
4: personB 2015         TRUE
```