# Subset dataframe in R using multiple inequality expressions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

## Problem

This question is an extension on the topic of subsetting using multiple logical conditions—particularly strict inequalities—to subset a data frame in R (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Say my variable ranges from 0 to 100. I need to create a subset that returns values that are between 50 and 100, but also values less than 25.

```
# Data
df$var = seq(1:100)

# Desired Subset
df$var[df$var > 50 & df$var < 100 & df$var < 25]
```

## Question

- What is the best way to make a subset involving multiple inequalities using base R?
- Are solutions using non-base R packages more elegant?

Comment: Two good `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions. Could someone address how this would work using `[ ]` subsetting for comparison? Or, explain why it isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP asks for base-R subset method and by looking at the answers (they seem to desire what OP wants), following will be helpful:

```
df$var[(df$var > 50 & df$var < 100) | df$var < 25]
```

If you want to have variables between 50 and 100 and **also** less than 25, then you need to use `|` operator (equivalent of OR, as you can see in the other answers) to get your desired subset. Look below for the output;

```
>
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 51 52 53 54 
#[29] 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 
#[57] 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` filters for this. Use "|" for "or".

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(var < 25 | (var > 50 & var < 100))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this logic, but have the result be only one vector of the data set? Starting with `df$var %>%` doesn't work.I have a similar problem trying to use: `df$var(df$var[which(df$var < 25 | (df$var > 50 & df$var< 100)),])`.

Comment: If you mean that the output should just be the `var` column, then add `%>% select(var)` to the end of the code in my answer.

Comment: And if you mean that the output should be a vector, then add `%>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)` after the `select`.

Comment: Great explanation for *how* to get just one column (i.e. `df$var`) and format it as a vector. I'm also interested to know the  *why* starting with `df$var %in%` wouldn't work.

Comment: Basically, because dplyr works on data frames and its functions work on columns or rows.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[var < 25 |(var > 50 & var < 100)]
```