# R selecting rows from dataframe using logical indexing: accessing columns by `$` vs `[]`

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple R `data.frame` object `df`. I am trying to select rows from this dataframe based on logical indexing from a column `col` in `df`.

I am coming from the python world where during similar operations i can either choose to select using `df[df[col] == 1]` or `df[df.col == 1]` with the same end result.

However, in the R data frame `df[df$col == 1]` gives an incorrect result compared to `df[df[,col] == 1]` (confirmed by `summary` command). I am not able to understand this difference as from links like http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html it seems that either way is ok. Also, `str` command on `df$col` and `df[, col]` shows the same output.

Is there any guidelines about when to use `$` vs `[]` operator ?

**Edit:**
digging a little deeper and using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or) as reference, it seems like the following code works correctly

`df[which(df$col == 1), ]`

however, not clear how to guard against `NA` and when to use `which`

Comment: Based on your examples I sort of wonder if you might be a little confused about the distinction between `[` and `[[` for lists (which includes data frames)? Because using single and double braces has different results. (See the top related question linked over at the right.)

Comment: thanks have edited the question

Comment: If you are interested in using the data.table package, you can subset rows based on a logical condition very easily. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

You confused many things.

In

```
df[,col]
```

col should be the column number.  For example,

```
col = 2
x = df[,col]
```

would select the second column and store it to x.

In

```
df$col
```

col should be the column name.  For example,

```
df=data.frame(aa=1:5,bb=10:14)
x = df$bb
```

would select the second column and store it to x.  But you cannot write `df$2`.

Finally,

```
df[[col]]
```

is the same as `df[,col]` if col is a number.  If col is a character ("character" in R means the same as string in other languages), then it selects the column with this name. Example:

```
df=data.frame(aa=1:5,bb=10:14)
foo = "bb"
x = df[[foo]]
y = df[[2]]
z = df[["bb"]]
```

Now x, y, and z are all contain the copy of the second column of df.

The notation `foo[[bar]]` is from lists. The notation `foo[,bar]` is from matrices.  Since dataframe has features of both matrix and list, it can use both.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` when you want to select **one** specific column by name `df$col_name`.

Use `[]` when you want to select **one or more** columns by number:

- `df[,1] # select column with index 1`
- `df[,1:3]# select columns with indexes 1 to 3`
- `df[,c(1,3:5,7)] # select columns with indexes 1, 3 to 5 and 7`.

`[[]]` is mostly for lists.

**EDIT**: `df[which(df$col == 1), ]` works because `which` function creates a logical vector which checks if the column index is equal to 1 (true) or not (false). This logical vector is passed to `df[]` and only true value is shown.

[Remove rows with NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame) - to find out more about how to deal with missing values. It is always a good practice to exclude missing values from dataset.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. @joran pointed out something similar in comments. Have edited the question -- sorry for the confusion

Comment: @goofd The use of `which` here would be to treat any `NA`s arising from the boolean comparison as FALSE. Otherwise, you'd be indexing by a boolean vector with (potentially) NA values in it, which would generate "NA rows". You will probably find there is some debate in the R community about this behavior.

Comment: that's really interesting... these quirks with `NA` 's in each language always gets me