# Why I get NA when I do indexing a vector (or dataframe) that do not match my condition?

Tags: r, indexing

When I do indexing a vector or dataframe in R, I sometimes get an empty vector (e.g. numeric(0), integer(0), or factor(0)...), and sometimes get NA.
I guess that I get NA when the vector or dataframe I deal with contains NA.

For example,

```
iris_test = iris
iris_test$Sepal.Length[1] = NA

iris[iris$Sepal.Length < 0, "Sepal.Length"] # numeric(0)
iris_test[iris_test$Sepal.Length < 0, "Sepal.Length"] # NA
```

It's intuitive for me to get numeric(0) when I find values that do not match my condition
(no search result --> no element in the resulted vector --> numeric(0)).
However, why I get NA rather than numeric(0)?

Comment: I intentionally give the awkward condition to get NA or an empty vector.

Comment: There are at least 4 base methods for subsetting dataframes. A1) "naked" `"["` with logical expression;  A2) "semi-clothed" `"[,expr]"`using the logical expression of your choice combined with  `&!is.na(expr); B) the `subset` function which uses the A2 strategy internally, and C) the `"["` function with a `which()` argument. They each have the advantages and disadvantages. This was discussed here and in several cogent comments to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or/4935551?r=SearchResults&s=1|63.8638#4935551

Comment: @42- Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is kind of correct that is you get `NA` values when there is `NA` in the data.

The comparison yields `NA` values

```
iris_test$Sepal.Length < 0
#[1]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE.....
```

When you subset a vector with `NA` it returns `NA`. See for example,

```
iris$Sepal.Length[c(1, NA)]
#[1] 5.1  NA
```

This is what the second case returns. For first case, all the values are `FALSE` so you get `numeric(0)`

```
iris$Sepal.Length[FALSE]
#numeric(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any explanation for the NA result (e.g. deduction from several first-hand principles)? or is it a first-hand rule per se?

Comment: @HoonTaek yes, it is present in `?Extract`. `When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Ronak's

The discussion of `NA` at [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#missing-values) makes it easy for me to understand `NA`. `NA` stands for `Not Available` which is a representation for an `unknown` values. According to the book linked above,  `missing values are "contagious"; almost any operation involving an unknown (NA) value will also be unknown`. Here are some examples:

```
# Is unknown greater than 0? Result is unknown (NA) 
NA > 0
#NA

# Is unknown less than 0? Output is unknown (NA). 
NA < 0
# NA

# Is unknown equal to unknown? Output is unknown(NA).  
NA == NA
# NA
```

Getting back to your data, when you do: 
`iris_test$Sepal.Length[1] = NA`,  you are assigning the value of `iris_test$Sepal.Length[1]` as  `"unknown" (NA)`.

The question is **"Is unknown less than 0?"**. 
The answer will be **unknown** and that is why you'r subsetting returns `NA` as output. The value is `unknown (NA)`.

There is a function called `is.na()` which I'm sure you're aware of to handle missing values.

Hope that adds some insight to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. R should say unknown in response to questions about the unknown.