# Filter rows by group level in R

Tags: r, subset

How would I select all the rows associated with years 2006, 2019, and 2020 (keep rows with NA too)?

```
> head(all_data)
      year     Tt
      <fct> <dbl>
    1 2006   NA  
    2 2020    5  
    3 2008   18  
    4 2018   41  
    5 2020   33.5
    6 2019    0.7
```

I tried this method, but I get an error:

```
mini_data <- all_data[(all_data$year==c('2020','2019','2006')),]

Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(rand$year, c("2020", "2019", "2006")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: replace `==` with `%in%`

Comment: You're awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Combining "which" with the "|" operator does the trick for me.

```
mini_data <- data[which(data$year== 2020 | data$year == 2019 | data$year == 2006),]
```

Excellent thread on this topic can be found here: [How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or)